# Loading nodes in JIT SpaceTree

Tags: php, javascript, json, space-tree

I try to use the SpaceTree from JIT and i realy need some help.
The problem is when try to load the tree from anothe array.

json.php

```
<?php
$temp = array(
    'id' => "node02",
    'name' => "roey",
    'data' => '',
    'children' => json_encode(array(
        'id' => "node13",
        'name' => "Some Node",
        'data' => '',
        'children' => '',

    )),
);
echo json_encode($temp);
```

my spacetree.js:

```
....
function init(){
$.getJSON('json.php', function(json){
    var json = json;
....
st.loadJSON(json);
```

The JSON that i receive is as expected,
but the script dont load it.

Does anyone see the problem and can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete from your code "var json = json". Variable json already declared in that function.
2. If "st.loadJSON(json);" not in function(json){ your code }.
   Variable json is local for function and can only be referenced within the function it is declared.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did what you said but now i got only the root node, the second show me undefined.

Answer (score -1):

i to was facing the same problem, JIT SpaceTree uses array of arrays for the children key, the php array should be like this

```
`<?php
$temp = array(
'id' => "node02",
'name' => "roey",
'data' => '',
'children' => array(array(
    'id' => "node13",
    'name' => "SomeNode",
    'data' => '',
    'children' =>array(),
),array(
    'id' => "node14",
    'name' => "SomeNode",
    'data' => '',
    'children' =>array(),
),
)
);
echo json_encode($temp);
?>`
```

hope this helps and saves time 4 others :)